# Excess space next to header

Tags: html, css

I'm having issues with excess space to the left of my header.

I had the same problem with my footer as well using `<nav>` and `<ul>`, but edited this to only using `<a>` elements instead, and this seemed to do the trick. I would, however, like to keep the `<nav>` in the header, and preferably **without using negative** `margin-left`.

https://jsfiddle.net/thereseel/d75jurzy/6/

```
<header>
 <nav>
  <ul class="mainnav">
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Logo</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Location</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: `ul` obtain the default CSS from the browser. In your case, you need to set the `padding-left:0` to the `ul`.

Answer (score 1):

you are facing excess space to the left of your header because of `ul`

browsers have default CSS values for many elements and `ul` is one of them.

from your current code just remove the padding

example:

```
.mainnav {
  /* add this to override default padding left of ul*/
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

Here is Reference of default CSS values used by browser : [w3schools link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp)

Comment: Great, this did remove the padding, but now the list items don't spread out in Chrome. It does in JSFiddle as well as Safari and Firefox
https://lybo.dev/htmlcss/ma3/

Comment: I am using chrome and it seems to be working fine to me

Comment: @Therese It's the effect of `flex`. You can use `justify-content: center;`. Let me know your desired output through a design

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code.
**HTML code:**

```
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul class="mainnav">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Logo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Location</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<div class="main-body">

</div>

<footer >
  <section class="footnav">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Order</a>
    <a href="#">Jobs</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </section>
</footer>
```

**CSS code:**

```
.main-body{
  min-height:500px;
}
.mainnav {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding-left:0px;
}

.mainnav li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.footnav {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
footer{
  position: fixed;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;

}
.footnav a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Hope it working.